Pytorch `DataSet.__getitem__()` called with `index` bigger than `__len__()`
I have following torch dataset (I have replaced actual code to read data from files with random number generation to make it minimal reproducible):
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torch 

class TempDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, window_size=200):
        
        self.window = window_size

        self.x = torch.randn(4340, 10, dtype=torch.float32) # None
        self.y = torch.randn(4340, 3, dtype=torch.float32) 

        self.len = len(self.x) - self.window + 1 # = 4340 - 200 + 1 = 4141 
                                                # Hence, last window start index = 4140 
                                                # And last window will range from 4140 to 4339, i.e. total 200 elements

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        # AFAIU, below if-condition should NEVER evaluate to True as last index with which
        # __getitem__ is called should be self.len - 1
        if index == self.len: 
            print('self.__len__(): ', self.__len__())
            print('Tried to access eleemnt @ index: ', index)
            
    return self.x[index: index + self.window], self.y[index + self.window - 1]

ds = TempDataset(window_size=200)
print('len: ', len(ds))
counter = 0 # no record is read yet
for x, y in ds:
    counter += 1 # above line read one more record from the dataset
print('counter: ', counter)

It prints:
len:  4141
self.__len__():  4141
Tried to access eleemnt @ index:  4141
counter:  4141

As far as I understand, __getitem__() is called with index ranging from 0 to __len__()-1. If thats correct, then why it tried to call __getitem__() with index 4141, when the length of the data itself is 4141?
One more thing I noticed is that despite getting called with index = 4141, it does not seem to return any elements, which is why counter stays at 4141
What my eyes (or brain) are missing here?
PS: Though it wont have any effect, just to confirm, I also tried to wrap DataSet with torch DataLoader and it still behaves the same.

I think the issue is that your TempDataset does not implement __iter__ or __next__ and neither does Dataset. I personally am not sure what it even comes up with as an iterator in this case, but it shouldn't work I think. You should subclass IterableDataset if you need to use it this way and implement __iter__.


First

I would like you to be more specific about what this code is for ? why are u using sliding windows and calling the dataset for what purpose as this is clearly not clear from the question u have given

Second :-

You missed out on calling index in the for loop at the end of the code  and interpreter cannot unpack so many tensors i suggest using enumerate()  which would help you achieve what u want
if u don't use enumerate then this would be the following error:-

therefore if u would pay more focus towards this
for index,(x, y)in enumerate(ds):
  print(f'Index:{index},shape : {x.shape}, y_shape:{y} ')
  counter += 1 
  print('counter: ', counter)

the output would be :- 

The use case is valid and not really relevant. enumerate() does not change the behavior so this doesn't answer the problem posed in the question.

but given the question doesnt really have a specificity mentioned so i assumed that the problem was why wasn't it showing right ? and i have given for that specific assumption and i am glad to know your opinion on how u have assumed the given question sean

I don't know what you're referring to 'showing'. The question is plainly about why the for loop indexes off the end of the dataset. Your output shows the exact same problem, so this is not a useful answer.

i got your point sean thanks for explaining it
